# Is ES5 shim still needed for Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, es5-shim

I am looking at the [compat tables](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#ie11), and it seems like IE 11 supports all of ES5 except (under Miscellaneous) this feature: "Enumerable properties can be shadowed by non-enumerables".  I don't understand what that means, despite the provided example.

Can I get away from using [ES5 shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) since IE11 supports most of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]Yes it is safe to drop ES5 shim in that scenario. I make websites available IE11 and common issues are custom variables, ES6 obviously and CSS calc() related bugs. Managed to make my own custom variable emulator using a map and used a similar approach CSS calc().

Answer (score 2):

The `length` property they use here, actually comes from the prototype of the `Function` constructor, [`Function.prototype.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) and returns the amount of arguments expected by the `function`. As you can see on the page I linked, the property is **not** enumerable, so `for ... in` should not enumerate the given property. The following snippet demonstrates that the property is not enumerable and therefore `result` will remain `true`.

```js
var result = true;
for(var propertyName in Function) {
  if(propertyName == 'length') {
    result = false;
  }
}

var isLengthEnumerable = Function.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable('length');
console.log('Function.prototype.length is enumerable: ' + isLengthEnumerable);
console.log('Result: ' + result);
```

The snippet above gives us the following output:

> Function.prototype.length is enumerable: false
>   Result: true

But in javascript, everything is an object and inherits properties from [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) through its prototype chain, including `Function`. So what happens when we assign the same property `length` to `Object.prototype`?

```js
var result1 = true;
var result2 = true;
Object.prototype.length = 42;
Object.prototype.otherProperty = 42;
for (var propertyName in Function) {
    if (propertyName == 'length') {
        result1 = false;
    }
    if (propertyName == 'otherProperty') {
        result2 = false;
    }
}

var isLengthEnumerable = Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable('length');
var isOtherPropertyEnumerable = Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable('otherProperty');
console.log('Object.prototype.length is enumerable: ' + isLengthEnumerable);
console.log('Object.prototype.otherProperty is enumerable: ' + isOtherPropertyEnumerable);
console.log('Result1: ' + result1);
console.log('Result2: ' + result2);
```

The above snippet gives us the following results:

> Object.prototype.length is enumerable: true
>   Object.prototype.otherProperty is enumerable: true
>   Result1: true
>   Result2: false

As the `Object.prototype.length` property we just assigned **is** enumerable, you would expect that `result1` would now be `false`. But because `Function` already has a `length` property (although not enumerable), the `length` property inherited from `Object.prototype` is not enumerated. The property has been **shadowed**.

This is what doesn't happen in IE11, there `Object.prototype.length` will be enumerated anyways and `result1` will become `false` as well.